# Unity | mesh.colors won't color my custom mesh object

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have build a custom pyramid in Unity like this:

```
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    mesh.Clear();
    Vector3[] vertices = {
        new Vector3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f),
        new Vector3(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f),
        new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.0f, 0.5f),
        new Vector3(-0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f),
        new Vector3(0.5f, 0.0f, -0.5f),
    };

    int[] triangles = {
        1, 2, 3,
        1, 3, 4,
        1, 0, 2,
        2, 0, 3,
        3, 0, 4,
        4, 0, 1
    };


    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
```

I am trying to color my pyramid, as said in unity documentation like this:

```
    Color[] colors = new Color[vertices.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        colors[i] = Color.Lerp(Color.red, Color.green, vertices[i].y);

    // assign the array of colors to the Mesh.
    mesh.colors = colors;
```

but this wont change a thing..

i have no materials on my object, only this script.
Any ideas?

Comment: what is set as material(s) in the MeshRenderer?

Comment: Nothing.. Should i use materials to color my pyramid? Sorry, i am 2 days in unity and glga :p

Comment: @derHugo I also udnerstand that i may have to use a shader..? I dont know how this works either.. I mean i have an idea about shaders but no how to use them in unity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Note that comment in [mesh.colors](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-colors.html)

> // (Note that most built-in Shaders don't display vertex colors. Use one that does, such as a Particle Shader, to see vertex colors)

so in order to see those colors in the `MeshRenderer` component add a material that uses such a Vertex or Particle Shader.

Therefore

1. in the `Project` view (Assets) do <kbd>right click</kbd> → `Create` → `Material`

   [image]
2. Give that material a name
3. For the `Shader` from the Dropdown menu find and select e.g. `Particles` → `Standard Unlit` (or if you want to receive lightning `Standard Surface`)

   [image]
4. Finally use this material for your object either by dragging it into the `MeshRenderer` → `material` or by simply dragging it onto the according object in the `Scene` view (the latter might not work if there is no mesh for that object yet)

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is an exemplary answer for us who are completely new to Unity. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55714190/617889:

When using **Universal Render Pipeline** you need to use other shaders:

- `Univeral Render Pipeline` \ `Particles` \ `Lit` (with lightning)
- `Univeral Render Pipeline` \ `Particles` \ `Unlit` (without lightning)

Comment: Works on Unity 2020+